# scala regex - find sentences between the period character

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying find sentences between two fullstops (period). I tried the following expression but this seems to skip every alternate sentence.

```
"\\..+?\\.".r.findAllIn("''Super Ducktales'' is an [[Ducktales]]'s episode.  ==Plot== ===Part 1:Liquid assetats=== When the Ma Beagle's birthday is next, the Beagles sabote the new Duckburg's freeway plant to make that the freeeway pass '''acroos''' the Money Bin. After discovery it, [[Scrooge McDuck]] goes talk with the pig major but he can't accept chenge the plant. After, at [[Manor McDuck]], Scrooge realize that he need contract a accounter.").foreach(println(_))
```

Output is:

```
.  ==Plot== ===Part 1:Liquid assetats=== When the Ma Beagle's birthday is next, the Beagles sabote the new Duckburg's freeway plant to make that the freeeway pass '''acroos''' the Money Bin.
. After, at [[Manor McDuck]], Scrooge realize that he need contract a accounter.
```

As a second part of this question, I would also like to extract the first sentence also. Is there any way to incorporate the ^ symbol?

Knowledge of scala is pretty limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because regex consumes as it moves along. Do this instead:

`"\\.[^.]+"`

Comment: Thanks, that helped, any way to extract the first sentence also in the regex which is not bounded between the fullstops?

Comment: `"""(^[^.]+|\.[^.]+)""".r`